# Derivative of an integral quantity involving a moving level set

Tags: calculus, riemannian-geometry

we have a Riemannian manifold (M, g), a smooth, proper function $u$ and a smooth function $f$.

I am stuck with computing the derivative along $r$ of the following quantity:

$$
I(r)=\int_{\{u=r\}} f d\sigma.
$$

I guess that actually a normal derivative of $f$ has to appear, as well as the mean curvature $H$ of $\{u=r\}$, coming from the derivative of the area element.

Anyway, I am not able to figure out a correct formula.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It is a bit more convenient to define
$$
 F(r) = \int_{\{u=r\}} f \, \frac{d\sigma}{|\nabla u|}. 
$$
That is because $|\nabla u|^{-1} \,d\sigma$ is a more natural surface measure for level sets, since it takes the *thickness* into account. That is large gradient gives a thin level set and small gradient gives a thick one.

In this case, it holds
$$
F'(r)= \int_{\{u=r\}} \operatorname{div}\left( f \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2}\right) \, \frac{d\sigma}{|\nabla u|} .
$$
By using the chain rule for the divergence, one recovers two contributions
$$
  \operatorname{div}\left( f \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2}\right)  = \nabla f \cdot \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2} + f \operatorname{div}\left( \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2}\right) .
$$ 
Hence, we see the two contribution you conjecture. The first is related to the normal derivative of $f$ and the second is related to the curvature of the level set itself.

To proof the formula, we note that for any smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ it holds by the co-area formula
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(r) g(r) \, dr = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\{u=r\}} f\ g(r) \frac{d\sigma}{|\nabla u|} \, dr = \int_M f \ g\circ u \  d{vol} . 
$$
Then, we can calculate with $g'$ instead of $g$ inside of the above formula
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(r) g'(r) \, dr  &= \int_M f\ g'\circ u \, d{vol}\\
&= \int_M f \ \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2} \cdot \nabla (g\circ u) \, d{vol}\\
&= - \int_M g\circ u \ \operatorname{div}\left( f \ \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2} \right) \, d{vol} \\
&= - \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(r) \int_{\{u=r\}} \operatorname{div}\left( f \ \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|^2} \right) \, \frac{d\sigma}{|\nabla u|} \, dr
\end{aligned}$$
Now, letting vary $g$ over all smooth functions, we identified the formula in the distributional sense.

Comment: Could you point me to a reference that can be cited for this or a similar result?

Comment: A reference for the mentioned co-area formula is "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions" by L. C. Evans and R. F. Gariepy.
Revised version 2015: https://doi.org/10.1201/b18333

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question: Is the formula you provided equivalent to the “time derivative for surface integral” formula in the Wikipedia page below? The notation there is  different, using the mean curvature. Could you explain whether these are equivalent? Thanks! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_evolution_of_integrals

Comment: More specifically the formula: $-\int_S C B_{\alpha}^{\alpha} f dS$